# Choosing $p$ and $q$ for an RSA simple example

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

Trying to understand how RSA works. For the sake of simplicity I chose $3$ and $7$ as $p$ and $q$. I want to encode message $M=20$. Obviously, my $N=3\times 7=21$, I need to chose $e$ which is coprime with $(p-1)(q-1)=(3-1)\times (7-1)=12$, I might choose $e=5$.

Now whatever $e$ I chose now to be coprime with $12$, it seems when I compute $C=M^e(\mod 21)$ I always get the very same $C=M=20$ as the ciphtertext.

The same I think happens if I choose $p$ and $q$ to be $5$ and $7$.

I feel this is something trivial but I would like to understand what rule I have violated by choosing **p** and **q** being **3** and **7** or **5** and **7**?

Comment: Please use Mathjax. Example: `$C=(p-1)(q-1)=(3-1)\cdot(7-1)=12=M^e \pmod {21}$` $\to C=(p-1)(q-1)=(3-1)\cdot(7-1)=12=M^e \pmod {21}.$

Comment: Note that $20\equiv -1\pmod {3\times 7}$ so you are just talking about odd powers of $-1$ here.

Comment: Well I guess that's because you're picking $M$ too close to $N$. In reality $N$ is supposed to be large, you've just stumbled on an edge case where the ciphertext is the same as the deciphered one. If instead of $M=20$ you picked $M=12$, you wouldn't get $12$ again as the ciphertext. Likewise if you picked a very large $N$ you wouldn't get $20$ for the ciphertext with $M=20$

Comment: What about 7 and 11?

Comment: You haven't violated anything. $M\equiv -1\bmod 21$, so $M^e\equiv -1\bmod 21$ for any odd exponent $e$. Try a different value for $M$ to get more variety.

Comment: The same thing happens with $(p,q)=(5,7)$ because $20\equiv 0\bmod 5$ and $20\equiv -1\bmod 7$. Therefore, if $e$ is odd, $20^e\equiv 20\bmod 5$ and $20^e\equiv 20\bmod 7$. So this is just another special case. Everything is working correctly.

Comment: To avoid such corner cases, you might want to try more substantial primes, such as $(p,q)=(71,83)$.